# javax.el.ELException on RichFaces fileUpload

Tags: jsf, file-upload, richfaces

If I deploy my webapp on a tomcat 8 with java 1.8, I got this error:

> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service()
>   for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/mywebapp] threw
>   exception [/fileupload.xhtml: Property 'listener' not found on type
>   mywebapp.UploadController] with root cause  javax.el.ELException:
>   /fileupload.xhtml: Property 'listener' not found on type
>   mywebapp.UploadController

Code of fileupload.xhtml:

```
 <rich:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{uploadController.listener}"
                         id="dataupload"
                         listHeight="100px"
                         maxFilesQuantity="100"/>
```

The class UploadController:

```
public class UploadController {
...
    public void listener(FileUploadEvent e) throws Exception {
       final UploadedFile item = e.getUploadedFile();
       ...
    }
}
```

If I start my webapp locally with a jetty, everything works perfectly.

Where is the error?

Comment: This problem suggests that RichFaces is missing in runtime class path and thus all RichFaces tags/components are treated as if they are plain text and thus ultimately all EL expressions in those tags would behave like value expressions (it's as if you're using plain HTML). To exclude the one and other, do other RichFaces components work fine? (or are you merely using it for the upload functionality?) Are you building in a different way for both servers or so?

Comment: It seems every method call is affected. I have e.g. also a commandButton whose actionListener is misunderstood.